# Modify or change password of windows active directory users in linux containers

Tags: linux, directory, passwords

Our application uses active directory for storing the user credentials and authenticate the user against this active directory. Our application has "Forgot Password"and "Change Password"  functionality.Currently we are upgrading this .net 4.8 application to .net 6 and intention is to containerize the application such that it can be run in linux container.

We are able to successfully run this .net6 application in windows machine.

We are facing the problems as part of linux containerisation : Not able to change the password of the user using the package - System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

How to fix this problem or any code that help us implementing the change password in active directory and that runs in linux container

Below is the code used for changing the password.

---

DirectoryAttributeModification passwordMod = new DirectoryAttributeModification();

passwordMod.Name = "unicodePwd";

passwordMod.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;

passwordMod.Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes('"' + newPassword + '"'));

// Create the modification request and send it to the directory

ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(entry.DistinguishedName, passwordMod);

// Failing this code in linux container

ModifyResponse modifyResponse = (ModifyResponse)connection.SendRequest(modifyRequest);

****************************************************************************************************

Expectedto have password  changed,but got an error in the line related to ModifyResponse.